# Аутентификация на странице корзины

Tags: php, wordpress

Использую этот код для автоматической аутентификации пользователя, если он находится на странице корзины и в get передан user_login пользователя.
`url` такой:

```
/cart/?add-to-cart=14034&quantity=1&name=username
```

Но пишет что корзина пуста.
А если передать такой `url`, т.е. без аутентификации

```
/cart/?add-to-cart=14034&quantity=1
```

то товар показывается.
Как можно исправить, чтобы была аутентификация и показывался товар?

```
add_action('wp', 'user_login');
function user_login(){
    if(is_cart()){
        $url = explode('?', '//'.$_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"] . $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]);
        if(!empty($url[1]) && strpos($url[1],'name')){
            parse_str($url[1],$urlArray);
            if(!empty($urlArray['name'])){
                programmatic_login($urlArray['name']);
            }
        }
    }
}

function programmatic_login( $username ) {

    if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
        wp_logout();
    }

    add_filter( 'authenticate', 'allow_programmatic_login', 10, 3 );    // hook in earlier than other callbacks to short-circuit them
    $user = wp_signon( array( 'user_login' => $username ) );
    remove_filter( 'authenticate', 'allow_programmatic_login', 10, 3 );

    if ( is_a( $user, 'WP_User' ) ) {
        wp_set_current_user( $user->ID, $user->user_login );

        if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}

/**
 * An 'authenticate' filter callback that authenticates the user using only the username.
 *
 * To avoid potential security vulnerabilities, this should only be used in the context of a programmatic login,
 * and unhooked immediately after it fires.
 *
 * @param WP_User $user
 * @param string $username
 * @param string $password
 * @return bool|WP_User a WP_User object if the username matched an existing user, or false if it didn't
 */
function allow_programmatic_login( $user, $username, $password ) {
    return get_user_by( 'login', $username );
}
```

**P.S.**

такое происходит, т.е. не отображается товар только если при переходе по вышеприведённой ссылке любой юзер аутентифицирован. А если нет, то данный код срабатывает. Как выйти из залогиненого юзера и авторизоваться новым?

Comment: Попробуйте другой гет-параметр, такая же проблема будет?

Comment: @Krya, да, ставил разные параметры, результат тотже

Comment: подскажете, из-за чего не показывается товар?